# Move TikZ cloud in a better position using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, text-manipulation

I am trying to manipulate the exact position of a TikZ `cloud` but I am not sure if I'm doing any effort at all.

[image]

As you see in the aforementioned picture the space between items is not beautiful. So I tried to add it outside the `itemize` enviroment. It seems, though that it's not following my commands. The code I am using is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item XY Resistive MM
    \item Manufactured by Rui de Oliveira \quad \uncover<1->{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,shading=ball,text=white,cloud callout,cloud puffs=17,cloud puff arc     =140,callout pointer segments=3,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(200:2 cm )},     aspect =2.5,scale=0.5]
at(current page.east){Thank you Rui!};
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \item bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,shading=ball,text=white,cloud callout,cloud puffs=17,cloud puff arc     =140,callout pointer segments=3,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(200:2 cm )},     aspect =2.5,scale=0.5]
at(current page.north east){Thank you Rui!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aw, *percusse* was faster. I basically did the same, but turned it into a macro with the parameters `[angle]{content}`:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\Cloud}[2][180]% [angle], content
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node[align=center, draw, shading=ball, text=white, cloud callout, cloud puffs=17, cloud puff arc=140, callout pointer segments=3, anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(#1:2 cm )}, aspect=4,scale=0.5] at (0.2ex,0.5ex) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item XY Resistive MM\Cloud{Thank you Rui}
    \item Manufactured by Rui de Oliveira\Cloud[160]{Thanks again}
    \item bla bla bla\Cloud[120]{Thanks yet another time}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Oh I think yours is much more structured, I've deleted mine. Can you include the obsolete options warning in your answer?

Comment: Actually, as I simplified the given MWE a lot, no such warnings appear for me.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! I really liked the `newcommand`. It is really fancy! Thank you both soooo much!!!

Comment: @percusse: did it in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another approach: at first the point where the cloud should start is marked and then the could is positioned starting from that position. The command `\mycallout` is overlay-aware therefore allows you some customization.

Notice that you can position a cloud regardless having marked a point, but doing it allows the pointer to be vertically aligned with respect the sentence (the last cloud is not).

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logopolito}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{xparse}

 \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycallout}{r<> m m}{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[visible on=<#1>,align=center,draw,shading=ball,text=white,cloud callout,cloud puffs=17,cloud puff arc=140,callout pointer segments=3,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(200:2cm)}, aspect =2.5,scale=0.5]
at (#2) {#3};
}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> XY Resistive MM
    \item<2-> Manufactured by Rui de Oliveira \tikzmark{this point}\quad 
     \mycallout<3>{this point}{Thank you Rui!}
    \item<4-> Another sentence with a callout \tikzmark{bla} \mycallout<5>{bla}{Bla bla bla}
\end{itemize}
\vfill
Another text. \mycallout<6>{0,0}{My text}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Percusse suggested to comment the warning deriving from your code:

- the option `slidetop`:

> Class beamer Warning: `slidestop'' is obsolete. Use`t'' instead on input lin
>   e 343.

- the option `mathserif`:

> Class beamer Warning: `mathserif'' is obsolete. Use font theme`serif'' with 
>   option ``onlymath'' on input line 343.

You can avoid them by means of substituting the first two lines in your code:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

Notice that also the `snakes` library is obsolete: you can use `decorations` although in the current example is not needed.

---

The equivalent `xparse`-free solution:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\mode<presentation>
%frame
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
     \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[July 2012 H4 Test Beam\hspace{3cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{July 2012 H4 Test Beam}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]        {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logopolito}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,shapes}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{paralist}

 \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\newcommand{\mycallout}[3]{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[visible on=<#1>,align=center,draw,shading=ball,text=white,cloud callout,cloud puffs=17,cloud puff arc=140,callout pointer segments=3,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(200:2cm)}, aspect =2.5,scale=0.5]
at (#2) {#3};
}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> XY Resistive MM
    \item<2-> Manufactured by Rui de Oliveira \tikzmark{this point}\quad 
     \mycallout{3}{this point}{Thank you Rui!}
    \item<4-> Another sentence with a callout \tikzmark{bla} \mycallout{5}{bla}{Bla bla bla}
\end{itemize}
\vfill
Another text. \mycallout{6}{0,0}{My text}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that writing thesis trim down the programming quickness `:D`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your comment, is striking directly on the spot :) But OK, I admit it: I am not a software guy...!!! The thing about your answer is that it isn't working on my system. Somehow `NewDocumentCommand` seems to be very nasty for my system...

Comment: My comment was related to the fact that it took to me too much time to write the answer. For what concern `NewDocumentCommand`: do you have problems with the `xparse` package? I've use it mainly to have the possibility of declaring as delimeters `<>` for the overlay specifications.