# TikZ callout pointing to nested align/text/math environment not displayed

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, presentations

See the MWE below. Observation: In the second version the callout is displayed in the first it is not.

Can anyone tell me why this is so?

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,shadows}
\usepackage{xparse}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycallout}{r<> O{opacity=0.8,text opacity=1} m m m m m m}{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[drop shadow, rounded corners, align=left, fill=#8!30, text width=#5,
#2,visible on=<#1>,
draw,rectangle callout,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(#6:#7cm)}]
at (#3) {#4};
}

\newcommand{\refbox}[3]{
\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node[fill=#3!30,anchor=base,rounded corners] (#1) {#2};
}

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{ABC}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% with this version the callout is not displayed %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{align*}                              
&\text{ $g(x)\refbox{rb2711121055}{$\sim$}{yellow} x^\alpha$}
\end{align*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% with this version the callout is displayed %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \begin{align*}                            
% \refbox{rb2711121055}{$2+2=4$}{yellow}
% \end{align*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mycallout<1>{rb2711121055.north}{$1<2$}{1cm}{230}{1}{yellow}

}
\end{document}
```

PS: The code is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83786/16865. I don't think the problem has anything to do with the complicated stuff at the beginning of the preamble but, not being sure, I didn't further reduce the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your `display math(text mode (inline math))` usage is affecting something. If you use a regular math environment it works after two runs.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz,lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,shadows}
\usepackage{xparse}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycallout}{r<> O{opacity=0.8,text opacity=1} m m m m m m}{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
{\node[drop shadow, rounded corners, align=left, fill=#8!30, text width=#5,
#2,visible on=<#1>,
draw,rectangle callout,anchor=pointer,callout relative pointer={(#6:#7cm)}]
at (#3) {#4};}
}
\newcommand{\refbox}[3]{
\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)]{ 
         \node[fill=#3!30,anchor=base,rounded corners] (#1) {#2};}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{ABC}

\[
g(x)\refbox{rb}{$\sim$}{yellow} x^\alpha
\]

\mycallout<1>{rb.north}{$1<2$}{1cm}{230}{1}{yellow}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But why just in the first example? I mean, the second is also display style!

Comment: @lpdbw I don't know (though you don't have text mode in the second example) but it's bad practice to use single lines with `align` anyway. Also `beamer` and `align` don't like each other that much.

Comment: HHmm, single line in `align`was just for the MWE. Actually, I have many lines and it's not clear how to do it w/o `align` :-(

Comment: @lpdbw You don't need to use `$...$` inside `\text` just close one type the math and open another `\text` so it should work as in your second example. Might be a boxing issue.

Comment: OK, yes ... `\begin{align*}
&\text{ abc } g(x)\refbox{rb2711121055}{$\sim$}{yellow} \text{ cde } x^\alpha
\end{align*}` works fine. Maybe you could put something like that in your answer so that I can accept it.