# Stating a short remark/point in beamer slides

Tags: beamer

In beamer (presentation), I had seen example of *insertion of a remark/small point* during the presentation as below.

There, the author speaks (during presentation) as follows

> "Consider the base case, namely when M/N is simple ... this work is done by Kleidmann, Liebeck,etc."

And while speaking this, he points out the names of Methematicians specifically as pointed below in slide.

**Q.** What are the commands to insert such pointing remarks, notes during slide presentation? (Please insert appropriate tag if necessary, since I do not have much idea of it.)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83786/134144

Comment: @leandriis: yes, really helpful, and almost exactly that question I posted. But I had no idea of appropriate language to write it. Thanks for suggestion.