# TikZ: \newcommand with optional TikZ options

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, optional-arguments

I want to create a new command with some default TikZ options that you can override using an optional argument. If working as intended the code below would generate a red line between A and B, and a translucent green line with arrows between A and C. How can I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\relation}[3][]
{
  % this needed to be modified somehow...
  \path [draw, red] (#2) -- (#3);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {A};
  \node [draw] (B) at (3, 0) {B};
  \node [draw] (C) at (3, 3) {C};
  \relation{A}{B}
  \relation[<->, color=green!10]{A}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You already have the solution. Put  `draw,red,#1` and it's good to go. However, it is better to use `draw=red` such that you can easily override it with `draw=none` without having the red color set for fill etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @TomBombadil answered in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74338/move-tikz-cloud-in-a-better-position-using-beamer/74344#74344) a way to do that is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\CloudRed}[2][180]% [angle], content
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \node[align=center, draw,  fill=red, text=white, cloud callout, cloud puffs=17, cloud puff arc=140, callout pointer segments=3, anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(#1:2 cm )}, aspect=4,scale=0.5] at (-3ex,0.5ex) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}
        \item XY Resistive MM\Cloud{Thank you Rui}
    \item Manufactured by Rui de Oliveira\Cloud[160]{Thanks again}
    \item bla bla bla\Cloud[120]{Thanks yet another time}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image]

As @percusse suggested just a little modification is needed to your code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\relation}[3][]
{
  % this needed to be modified somehow...
  \path [draw=red,#1] (#2) -- (#3);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw] (A) at (0, 0) {A};
  \node [draw] (B) at (3, 0) {B};
  \node [draw] (C) at (3, 3) {C};
  \relation{A}{B}
  \relation[<->, color=green!40!black!100]{A}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Your first code has problems. Here's a suggested fix based on your code (I've made colors as parameters too): http://pastebin.com/9VAT0YLJ

Comment: I'm wondering how this can be extended to also use a an argument in normal braces, as in \mynode[draw] (name) {something} ?