# How to draw the following picture?

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to do this drawing:

[image]

However, I can do only the next drawing, which is still far from achieving what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [] (-1.5,-2) rectangle  (5,5);
\fill [draw=yellow,fill=yellow!50,
postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,text along path,
text=Divisibility Rule Poetry!!}}]
(0,2) arc (140:-180:2.5cm and 1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please format your code? Look in the callout shapes library for the call out. Maybe use a font smiley for the smiley. Or `tikzsymbols`.

Comment: Are you interested in drawing the smiley face and thought bubble and...?

Comment: Werner- I intend to draw

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74344/586 shows you a method for making the thought bubble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shapes}
\tikzset{%
    pics/Cloud/.style={code={%
            \node[align=center, draw,scale=5, fill=white, text=black, cloud callout, cloud puffs=16, cloud puff arc=140, callout pointer segments=2, anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(320:3pt)}, aspect=2] {};
    }}, 
    pics/Ball/.style 2 args={code={%
            \shade[ball color=#1] circle (0.55); 
            \node[circle, fill=white] at (0.1,0) {#2};
    }}, 
}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=orange!40!white] (0,0) rectangle  (7.5,9);
    \draw [blue] (1,1) rectangle  (6.5,7);
    \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=4pt,text color={red!90!black},
            text={|\Large|DIVISIBILITY RULE POETRY!!}}}]
    (.7,6.5) to[bend left=65] (6.8,6.5);
    \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-10pt,text color={blue},
            text={|\small|By what numbers is 54 divisible?}}}]
    (1.25,7) -- (6,7);
    \node at (4.5,2.7) {\dSey[11]};
    \pic at (4.5,4.2) {Cloud};
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (2.2,5.7) {Ball={yellow}{1}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (2.3,5.05) {Ball={yellow!90!black}{5}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (3,5.9) {Ball={blue}{2}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (3,5.1) {Ball={green}{6}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (3.7,4.9) {Ball={red}{3}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (3.7,5.7) {Ball={yellow}{9}}; 
    \pic[scale=.5, transform shape] at (4.3,5.5) {Ball={violet}{4}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: CarLaTeX's. Thanos. Show.

Comment: @benedito Do you mean [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos)? :):):)

Comment: CarLaTeX, Yes. I like it very much.

Comment: @benedito You're welcome for the comparison, then!